# why digraph not defined in matlab2011?

Tags: matlab, digraphs

I have this error when wrote digraph in matlab 2011a:

> help digraph.
>   digraph not found.
>   Use the Help browser search field to search the documentation, or type "help help" for help command options, such as help for methods.

I want to use digraph. how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a newer version of Matlab. According to [this documentation page](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/digraph.html), the function `digraph` was introduced in version R2015b.